# Set up a firewall for AppEgnine for specific website and IP addresses

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, firewall

I have an API in Appengine and I want to allow only specific IP addresses and a specific website to request from it

For example I want the website foo.com to make requests as well as IP 1.2.3.4

I've looked here but it only mentions IP addresses
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/creating-firewalls

I don't want to use a key as the API request will be available on the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address of the site you want to whitelist shouldn't change. You can safely do a DNS lookup to get the host IP of the site and add that to the firewall.

For example:

```sh
$ host example.com
example.com has address 93.184.216.34
example.com has IPv6 address 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```

So to whitelist example.com your IP range would be `93.184.216.34/32`

The main advantage to whitelist domains based on IP is that the requests you're receiving may not necessarily come from that IP. When you resolve the DNS and get an IP, what you're really getting is a gateway for incoming requests that can be routed to different servers.